# ReSharper and the C# reflection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

How can I get the code of MS built-in functions or classes by ReSharper?
How can I get the implementation code of **`string`** ?

Comment: You do know that the core libraries are open source now right? With that said, the classes you mention are implemented (the important parts anyway) using native code in the clr itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tool 'dotPeek' from JetBrains (creators of ReSharper) for decompiling any .NET assembly.

[dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Note: dotPeek can not decompile if the assembly is obfuscated.Microsoft .NET library is not obfuscated and you can decompile to the source code (Except native code).